# Can I use spark to parse html file?

Tags: html, apache-spark, beautifulsoup, pyspark, hdfs

I am facing a problem:

I want to parse a bunch of html files in **HDFS**, and I want to use **spark** to process them. For convenient, I want to use **pyspark**, and also want to use the powerful package **BeautifulSoup** to parse the html files. Is it possible for me to do that? And how can read the files from HDFS by using BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the html files are in HDFS, you could pipe a list of the file names into the driver, assigning a random number between 0 and the number of executors in your job. Then put this data into an rdd with parallelize. GroupyBy the random number and do a mapPartitions. The reducer function would process each row of the partition by reading the file in as text from HDFS. Then pass the text to BeautifulSoup and do your processing. Return results will be captured in an RDD. Keep in mind, that BeautifulSoup must be installed on each of your worker nodes or this will not work.

Comment: So how to pass the processed text to BeautifulSoup?